# what are "live" objects in java heap? (heap dump with jmap)

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-dump, jmap

**jmap** help shows:

...

> ```
> -dump:<dump-options> to dump java heap in hprof binary format
>                     dump-options:
>                       live         dump only live objects; if not specified,
>                                    all objects in the heap are dumped.
> ```
>
> ...

Once I dump a Tomcat (with java param -Xmx384m) heap:

```
jmap -dump:file=dump.bin <pid>
```

I got a dump file of ~300M.

When I dump its heap with *live* objects only:

```
jmap -dump:live,file=live-dump.bin <pid>
```

I got a dump file of ~120M.

My guess of *live* objects may be:

1. Objects in young generation;
2. Objects that are used / referenced / reachable and will not be collected.

Which one is right?

**UPDATE**

My guess #2 seems correct, and thanks for Alexey Ragozin's explanation (`live` option will cause a full GC). I tested again according to his hint:

```
jmap -dump:file=dump.hprof <pid>
jmap -dump:live,file=live-dump.hprof <pid>
jmap -dump:file=after-live-dump.hprof <pid>
```

size of these 3 files are:

```
dump.hprof ~190MB
live-dump.hprof ~40MB
after-live-dump.hprof ~40MB
```

so after `-dump:live`, almost all objects in heap are live.

Comment: @Holger sorry for my poor english. #2 I mean objects that are **no longer** used / referenced but not collected yet.

Comment: sorry for my stupid mistake :-p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`jmap -dump:live,file=live-dump.bin <pid>`

**live** option in jmap command below forces JVM to do a full GC before dumping content of heap into a file.

After full GC only objects transitively reachable from GC roots (definition of "live") are remaining in heap.

Comment: When you use live option, full GC is performed by the JVM which could literally hang the application until its complete, in some cases takes a long time and it may not even finish for application that use large heaps. In such cases, there is a good chance of getting the heap dump done if you drop the live option